# how do i set up a grails environment variable

Tags: grails, groovy, environment-variables

I'm uploading images in a grails app I'm developing and I want to be able to have an environment variable the determines where these images are. So if I'm working locally it can just pull from /home/MyName/images but once it's in production it will pull from http://images.site.com. How would I do that? I'm assuming i can set up my config.groovy with the variables i'm just not sure how i switch between them or use them in code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-Dgrails.env=foo` to specify the environment, where foo is defined in your config file:

```
environments {
   foo {
       setting = "bar"
   }
}
```

It's all in the docs, have a look at [Environment](http://www.grails.org/Environments) and [Config](http://www.grails.org/Config).

Comment: Thank you I've been looking for those exact pages.